# MongoDB $or query against itself much faster

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongo instance with 16m documents in a collection. I was writing a query to search for one of the (indexed) fields and I'm getting some weird results, which I cannot explain.

If I execute a query directly like:

```
find({ "$and" : [ { "ipAddr" : { "$regex" : "^01:172"}} , { "active" : true}]}).limit(100).sort({ "_id" : 1})
```

or even adding a pointless $or to the query:

```
find({ "$and" : [ { "$or" : [ { "ipAddr" : { "$regex" : "^01:172"}}]} , { "active" : true}]}).limit(100).sort({ "_id" : 1})
```

It returns
Fetched 3 record(s) in 71673ms

However, if I use an $or against itself like:

```
find({ "$and" : [ { "$or" : [ { "ipAddr" : { "$regex" : "^01:172"}} , { "ipAddr" : { "$regex" : "^01:172"}}]} , { "active" : true}]}).limit(100).sort({ "_id" : 1})
```

It returns:
Fetched 3 record(s) in 4ms

So a big performance difference. From inspecting the explain() on the queries, I could not determine why such a large performance difference exists. Can anyone shed light on what I'm missing or what mongo is doing differently between these?

Explain() on single $or which takes >60000ms

```
find({ "$and" : [ { "$or" : [ { "ipAddr" : { "$regex" : "^01:172"}}]} , { "active" : true}]}).limit(100).sort({ "_id" : 1}).explain()
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "CLS-TEST.Leases",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [
                {
                    "active" : {
                        "$eq" : true
                    }
                },
                {
                    "ipAddr" : /^01:172/
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "SORT",
            "sortPattern" : {
                "_id" : 1
            },
            "limitAmount" : 100,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "filter" : {
                        "active" : {
                            "$eq" : true
                        }
                    },
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "ipAddr" : 1
                        },
                        "indexName" : "ipAddr_1",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "isUnique" : false,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 1,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "ipAddr" : [
                                "[\"01:172\", \"01:173\")",
                                "[/^01:172/, /^01:172/]"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [
            {
                "stage" : "SORT",
                "sortPattern" : {
                    "_id" : 1
                },
                "limitAmount" : 100,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "filter" : {
                            "ipAddr" : /^01:172/
                        },
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "active" : 1,
                                "sessionId" : 1,
                                "updateTime" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "active_1_sessionId_1_updateTime_1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 1,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "active" : [
                                    "[true, true]"
                                ],
                                "sessionId" : [
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ],
                                "updateTime" : [
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "stage" : "SORT",
                "sortPattern" : {
                    "_id" : 1
                },
                "limitAmount" : 100,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "filter" : {
                            "ipAddr" : /^01:172/
                        },
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "active" : 1,
                                "clientId" : 1,
                                "startTime" : -1,
                                "_id" : -1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "active_1_clientId_1_startTime_-1__id_-1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 1,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "active" : [
                                    "[true, true]"
                                ],
                                "clientId" : [
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ],
                                "startTime" : [
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                ],
                                "_id" : [
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "stage" : "SORT",
                "sortPattern" : {
                    "_id" : 1
                },
                "limitAmount" : 100,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "active" : 1,
                                "ipAddr" : 1,
                                "startTime" : -1,
                                "_id" : -1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "active_1_ipAddr_1_startTime_-1__id_-1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 1,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "active" : [
                                    "[true, true]"
                                ],
                                "ipAddr" : [
                                    "[\"01:172\", \"01:173\")",
                                    "[/^01:172/, /^01:172/]"
                                ],
                                "startTime" : [
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                ],
                                "_id" : [
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "stage" : "SORT",
                "sortPattern" : {
                    "_id" : 1
                },
                "limitAmount" : 100,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "filter" : {
                            "ipAddr" : /^01:172/
                        },
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "active" : 1,
                                "macAddress" : 1,
                                "startTime" : -1,
                                "_id" : -1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "active_1_macAddress_1_startTime_-1__id_-1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 1,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "active" : [
                                    "[true, true]"
                                ],
                                "macAddress" : [
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ],
                                "startTime" : [
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                ],
                                "_id" : [
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "stage" : "SORT",
                "sortPattern" : {
                    "_id" : 1
                },
                "limitAmount" : 100,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "filter" : {
                            "ipAddr" : /^01:172/
                        },
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "active" : 1,
                                "remoteId" : 1,
                                "startTime" : -1,
                                "_id" : -1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "active_1_remoteId_1_startTime_-1__id_-1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 1,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "active" : [
                                    "[true, true]"
                                ],
                                "remoteId" : [
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ],
                                "startTime" : [
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                ],
                                "_id" : [
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "stage" : "LIMIT",
                "limitAmount" : 100,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "filter" : {
                        "$and" : [
                            {
                                "active" : {
                                    "$eq" : true
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "ipAddr" : /^01:172/
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "_id" : 1
                        },
                        "indexName" : "_id_",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "isUnique" : true,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 1,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "_id" : [
                                "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "3.2.3",
        "gitVersion" : "b326ba837cf6f49d65c2f85e1b70f6f31ece7937"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Explain() on $or against itself which takes <50ms

```
find({ "$and" : [ { "$or" : [ { "ipAddr" : { "$regex" : "^01:172"}} , { "ipAddr" : { "$regex" : "^01:172"}}]} , { "active" : true}]}).limit(100).sort({ "_id" : 1}).explain()
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "CLS-TEST.Leases",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [
                {
                    "$or" : [
                        {
                            "ipAddr" : /^01:172/
                        },
                        {
                            "ipAddr" : /^01:172/
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "active" : {
                        "$eq" : true
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "SORT",
            "sortPattern" : {
                "_id" : 1
            },
            "limitAmount" : 100,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "filter" : {
                        "active" : {
                            "$eq" : true
                        }
                    },
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "ipAddr" : 1
                        },
                        "indexName" : "ipAddr_1",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "isUnique" : false,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 1,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "ipAddr" : [
                                "[\"01:172\", \"01:173\")",
                                "[/^01:172/, /^01:172/]"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [
            {
                "stage" : "SORT",
                "sortPattern" : {
                    "_id" : 1
                },
                "limitAmount" : 100,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "filter" : {
                            "$or" : [
                                {
                                    "ipAddr" : /^01:172/
                                },
                                {
                                    "ipAddr" : /^01:172/
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "active" : 1,
                                "sessionId" : 1,
                                "updateTime" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "active_1_sessionId_1_updateTime_1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 1,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "active" : [
                                    "[true, true]"
                                ],
                                "sessionId" : [
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ],
                                "updateTime" : [
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "stage" : "SORT",
                "sortPattern" : {
                    "_id" : 1
                },
                "limitAmount" : 100,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "filter" : {
                            "$or" : [
                                {
                                    "ipAddr" : /^01:172/
                                },
                                {
                                    "ipAddr" : /^01:172/
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "active" : 1,
                                "clientId" : 1,
                                "startTime" : -1,
                                "_id" : -1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "active_1_clientId_1_startTime_-1__id_-1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 1,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "active" : [
                                    "[true, true]"
                                ],
                                "clientId" : [
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ],
                                "startTime" : [
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                ],
                                "_id" : [
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "stage" : "SORT",
                "sortPattern" : {
                    "_id" : 1
                },
                "limitAmount" : 100,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "filter" : {
                            "$or" : [
                                {
                                    "ipAddr" : /^01:172/
                                },
                                {
                                    "ipAddr" : /^01:172/
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "active" : 1,
                                "ipAddr" : 1,
                                "startTime" : -1,
                                "_id" : -1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "active_1_ipAddr_1_startTime_-1__id_-1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 1,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "active" : [
                                    "[true, true]"
                                ],
                                "ipAddr" : [
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ],
                                "startTime" : [
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                ],
                                "_id" : [
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "stage" : "SORT",
                "sortPattern" : {
                    "_id" : 1
                },
                "limitAmount" : 100,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "filter" : {
                            "$or" : [
                                {
                                    "ipAddr" : /^01:172/
                                },
                                {
                                    "ipAddr" : /^01:172/
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "active" : 1,
                                "macAddress" : 1,
                                "startTime" : -1,
                                "_id" : -1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "active_1_macAddress_1_startTime_-1__id_-1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 1,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "active" : [
                                    "[true, true]"
                                ],
                                "macAddress" : [
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ],
                                "startTime" : [
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                ],
                                "_id" : [
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "stage" : "SORT",
                "sortPattern" : {
                    "_id" : 1
                },
                "limitAmount" : 100,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "filter" : {
                            "$or" : [
                                {
                                    "ipAddr" : /^01:172/
                                },
                                {
                                    "ipAddr" : /^01:172/
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "active" : 1,
                                "remoteId" : 1,
                                "startTime" : -1,
                                "_id" : -1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "active_1_remoteId_1_startTime_-1__id_-1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 1,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "active" : [
                                    "[true, true]"
                                ],
                                "remoteId" : [
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ],
                                "startTime" : [
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                ],
                                "_id" : [
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "stage" : "LIMIT",
                "limitAmount" : 100,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "filter" : {
                        "$and" : [
                            {
                                "$or" : [
                                    {
                                        "ipAddr" : /^01:172/
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "ipAddr" : /^01:172/
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "active" : {
                                    "$eq" : true
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "_id" : 1
                        },
                        "indexName" : "_id_",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "isUnique" : true,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 1,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "_id" : [
                                "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "3.2.3",
        "gitVersion" : "b326ba837cf6f49d65c2f85e1b70f6f31ece7937"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might note that none of the index selections include the combination of `"active"` and `"ipAddr"`, which would be the useful index to define here.

In short, the "slower" query is using just the index for `"ipAddr"` and therefore it's taking more work to then "filter" out the `{ "active": true }` entries.

Clearly when the other index selection(s) are using the `"active"` key with those bounds there are less results being passed to the subsequent filter on the regex pattern. You seem to have quite a few indexes here, and none of them are really optimal for the query.

I'll give you props for at least running the "explain" output on either query, but if you look closely then you should see that the "slow" query "incorrectly" chooses the `"ipAddr"` index thinking it to be optimal. It might not be, but it's a reasonable assumption for the optimiser to make considering an "anchored" regex in use.

The [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) forces ["index intersection"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-intersection/), and it's smart enough to not do that when there is only "one" argument in the `$or`. "Two" arguments makes that happen, and the optimiser takes another "guess" by looking for an index preceeding with your other query condition ( the `"active"` value ).

That makes sense, since this is now running "two" queries from which it wil "intersect" the results, and therefore any conditions outside of the `$or` statement would be the logical choice to optimally choose an index for.

Since the returned results from these is likely smaller, it's therefore faster to "filter" out the regex match than to look at all the regex results and filter out the "active" values.

Therefore the "best" index to define for this query would be:

```js
.createIndex({ "active": 1, "ipAddr": 1 })
```

And then the results from either query would be consistent, providing of course that the optimiser does not get confused by other indexes present and chooses that one. To force the index selection, use [`.hint()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.hint/)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response and pointer to "index intersection". I was hoping to avoid creating an additional index, as the other indexes to reduce the maintenance overhead, but maybe it is required.

Comment: @caverman As to the number of indexes, you might want to take a good look at all your query patterns ( and explain outputs ) and decide if you really need them. It would probably be best to just have the compound indexes where the indexed keys are "optimally" used, and therefore preceeding with the most common combinations and the results they are likely to filter. The lesson here is mostly that `"active"` is the real value reducing possible results, and for this query at least that value is going to make the most difference as the preceeding entry within an index.